# Creat UIButton that activate UISwitch

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiswitch

As the title says; how can i create a UIButton that activate a UISwitch, and if it already is on, then deactivate it..?

Comment: What exact problem/question do you have?

Comment: i cant figure out how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have a

```
IBOutlet UISwitch * myNiceSwitch;
```

you can drop a push button (UIButton) into your view and connect it to an IBAction which then activates (or in my case below, toggles) your UISwitch:

```
- (IBAction) pushButtonAction: (id) sender
{
    BOOL switchEnabled = myNiceSwitch.enabled;

    myNiceSwitch.enabled = !switchEnabled;
}
```

Should be as simple as that, yes?